# Javascript Function Onclick change div high

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement a function where when I click on div the high of div change 600 from 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function resizeDiv(id)
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        if (obj)
        {
            obj.setAttribute("style", "height:600px;");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Just call the resizeDiv function with proper id of the DIV tag. like :

```
resizeDiv('idOfDiv');
```

Comment: Can we add Hide button to set default size

Comment: Please feel free to modify 'resizeDiv' function to accept a height parameter. Then call the same function with different heights to either enlarge or bring back to normal size.